# Dropdown vs. Person or Group Column in SharePoint List / PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint, dropdown, powerapps

I would like to filter a gallery by a dropdown. This is a solution I have successfully used in the past. The issue I am having currently is as follows. The dropdown contains information from a Person or Group field (one even with multiple choice) in a SharePoint List. How can I make this work?

For all other dropdown I am using:

```
ClearCollect(SOURCE, {Value:" All"}, Choices([@'SOURCE'].'FIELD'));
```

I would like to do something similar but for a Person or Group column/field.

Answer (score 0):

Filter(source,Dropdown1.Selected.Result="smt",Dropdown2.Selected.Email="smt")

Dropdown1 is regular text field, dropdown2 is person field.
Keep in mind that person field contains multiple props (same as sharepoint list item) like display name, email, etc.